# Fast database access test from .NET

Tags: .net, database, connection, connection-string

What would be a very fast way to determine if your connectionstring lets you connect to a database?

Normally a connection attempt keeps the user waiting a long time before notifying the attempt was futile anyway.

Comment: What about connecting to the target machine and port over tcp/ip and seeing if theres something listening there. I often telnet to a port just to see if something accepts the connection.

Comment: that might work, but creates other code than the standard database connection library, plus it doesn't guarantee the database will accept your connection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what database you are connecting to, however. In [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005), from .NET, you can specify a connection timeout in your connection string like so:

```
server=<server>;database=<database>;uid=<user>;password=<password>;Connect Timeout=3
```

This will try to connect to the server and if it doesn't do so in three seconds, it will throw a timeout error.

Answer (score 2):

Shorten the timeout on the connection string and execute something trivial.

The wait should be about the same as the timeout.

You would still need a second or two though.